# Android CalendarView change fontFamily

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles, calendarview

I'm trying to change the fontFamily of a CalendarView in xml, but it's not happening. Below is the code :

CalendarView :

```
<CalendarView
    android:id="@+id/calendar_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:dateTextAppearance="@style/CalendarViewTheme" 
 />
```

**styles.xml :**

```
    <style name="CalendarViewTheme" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small">
        <item name="android:textSize">14.5sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/calendar_text_color</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/sf_pro_semi_bold</item>
    </style>
```

**calendar_text_color.xml :**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/colorWhite" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/colorWhite" android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/colorWhite" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/colorWhite" android:state_activated="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/colorHints" android:state_enabled="false" />
    <item android:color="@color/colorBlack" />
</selector>
```